# How to save dynamic JSF form into database using Hibernate and spring

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc, primefaces

We are using JSF Primefaces 3.2.
I have a module where user will create some dynamic fields with his own choice like textfield, textarea, selectbox, checkbox, radio button then a form will generated on the basis of these selected fields.
I have successfully created the first part of this where user is creating form and generated the form according to his choice. But now i am facing the problem that how to save this form into the database.
Here i am attaching some code of my module so that will be easy for you to understand and find the solution quickly.

Here is the JSF form where i have generated all the fields using dynamically

```
    <h:form id="formObjectiveLibrary">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="form-table" columnClasses="column_1, column_2, column_3">
        <h:outputText value="Choose from Templates" />
        <p:selectOneListbox id="objectiveTemplateID" value="#{objectiveTemplateAction.objectiveTemplateID}" style="height: 120px; width: 200px">
        <f:selectItems value="#{objectiveTemplateAction.objectiveTemplateList}" var="template" itemLabel="#{template.title}" itemValue="#{template.id}"></f:selectItems>
        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{objectiveTemplateAction.loadTemplateQuestionsByID()}" update="libraryQuestionContainer"/>
        </p:selectOneListbox>
        <p:message for="objectiveTemplateID"/>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:outputPanel id="libraryQuestionContainer">
        <p:outputPanel rendered="#{objectiveTemplateAction.questionList.size() > 0}">
        <div class="tabbable tabs-left" style="margin-top: 20px; text-align: left;"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#inspection" data-toggle="tab">Inspection</a></li>
            <li><a href="#observation" data-toggle="tab">Observation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#rangeOfMotion" data-toggle="tab">Range of Motion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#strength" data-toggle="tab">Strength</a></li>
            <li><a href="#neuroVascular" data-toggle="tab">Neuro-Vascular</a></li>
            <li><a href="#specialTests" data-toggle="tab">Special Tests</a></li>
            <li><a href="#palpation" data-toggle="tab">Palpation</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="inspection">
                <ui:repeat var="q" varStatus="current" value="#{objectiveTemplateAction.questionList}">
                <p:outputPanel rendered="#{q.questionContainerName eq 'INSPECTION'}">
                    <h:panelGrid>
                    <p:outputPanel>
                        #{current.index + 1}. <h:outputText value="#{q.questionTitle}" />
                    </p:outputPanel>
                    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{q.questionType.questionTypeVariant eq 'textfield'}">
                        <h:inputText id="txtField" value=""/>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{q.questionType.questionTypeVariant eq 'comment'}">
                        <h:inputTextarea id="comment" cols="100" rows="5" value=""/>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{q.questionType.questionTypeVariant eq 'description_text'}">

                    </p:outputPanel>
                    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{q.questionType.questionTypeVariant eq 'multi_textbox'}">
                        <ui:repeat var="txt" value="#{q.questionOptionsList}">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="form-table" columnClasses="column1, column2">
                            <h:outputText value="#{txt.optionName}" />
                            <h:inputText id="multiText" value=""/>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{q.questionType.questionTypeVariant eq 'multi_numeric_textbox'}">
                        <ui:repeat var="numeric" value="#{q.questionOptionsList}">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="form-table" columnClasses="column1, column2">
                            <h:outputText value="#{numeric.optionName}" />
                            <pe:inputNumber id="numericTxt" value=""/>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{q.questionType.questionTypeVariant eq 'checkbox'}">
                        <p:selectManyCheckbox id="check" value="#{q.questionOptionsList}" layout="pageDirection">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{q.questionOptionsList}" var="chk" itemLabel="#{chk.optionName}" itemValue="#{chk.id}"/>  
                        </p:selectManyCheckbox>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{q.questionType.questionTypeVariant eq 'radio'}">
                        <p:selectOneRadio id="radio" value="#{objectiveTemplateAction.optionValue.optionValue}" layout="pageDirection">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{q.questionOptionsList}" var="rd" itemLabel="#{rd.optionName}" itemValue="#{rd.id}"/>  
                        </p:selectOneRadio>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{q.questionType.questionTypeVariant eq 'matrix_radio'}">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tbody>
                            <ui:repeat var="mrow" value="#{q.questionOptionsList}">
                            <p:outputPanel rendered="#{mrow.optionPosition eq 'ROW'}">
                                <tr>
                                <td>#{mrow.optionName}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <p:selectOneButton id="mradio" value="">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{objectiveTemplateAction.getColumnOptionsList(q.questionOptionsList)}" var="mr" itemLabel="#{mr.optionName}" itemValue="#{mr.id}"/>
                                    </p:selectOneButton>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                            </p:outputPanel>
                            </ui:repeat>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{q.questionType.questionTypeVariant eq 'matrix_checkbox'}">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tbody>
                            <ui:repeat var="checkrow" value="#{q.questionOptionsList}">
                            <p:outputPanel rendered="#{checkrow.optionPosition eq 'ROW'}">
                                <tr>
                                <td>#{checkrow.optionName}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <p:selectManyButton id="mcheck" value="#{q.questionOptionsList}">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{objectiveTemplateAction.getColumnOptionsList(q.questionOptionsList)}" var="mc" itemLabel="#{mc.optionName}" itemValue="#{mc.id}"/>
                                    </p:selectManyButton>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                            </p:outputPanel>
                            </ui:repeat>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{q.questionType.questionTypeVariant eq 'matrix_select'}">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <p:outputPanel rendered="#{q.questionOptionMenuList.size() gt 0}">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <ui:repeat value="#{q.questionOptionMenuList}" var="m">
                                <th>#{m.menuTitle}</th>
                                </ui:repeat>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                        <tbody>
                            <ui:repeat var="selectrow" value="#{q.questionOptionsList}">
                            <p:outputPanel rendered="#{selectrow.optionPosition eq 'ROW'}">
                                <tr>
                                <td>#{selectrow.optionName}</td>
                                <ui:repeat value="#{q.questionOptionMenuList}" var="m">
                                    <td>
                                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{m.questionOptionMenuChoiceList}" style="width: auto;">
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{m.questionOptionMenuChoiceList}" var="choice" itemLabel="#{choice.choiceName}" itemValue="#{choice.id}"/>
                                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                                    </td>
                                </ui:repeat>
                                </tr>
                            </p:outputPanel>
                            </ui:repeat>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{q.questionType.questionTypeVariant eq 'rating'}">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tbody>
                            <ui:repeat var="orow" value="#{q.questionOptionsList}">
                            <tr>
                                <td>#{orow.optionName}</td>
                                <td>
                                <p:selectOneButton id="rating" value="">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{q.questionOptionRatingList}" var="rating" itemLabel="#{rating.ratingLabel}" itemValue="#{rating.id}"/>
                                </p:selectOneButton>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </ui:repeat>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:outputPanel>
                </ui:repeat>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="observation">
                <p>A</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="rangeOfMotion">
                <p>sanjay</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="strength">
                <p>A</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="neuroVascular">
                <p>B</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="specialTests">
                <p>C</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="palpation">
                <p>D</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="form-table" columnClasses="column_1, column_2, column_3">
            <h:outputText value="" />
            <p:commandButton style="text-align: center" actionListener="#{objectiveTemplateAction.fillAndSaveTemplate}" 
                    styleClass="btn" value="Save" update="@form :mainErrorMessages" process="@form"/>
            <h:outputText value="" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>
        <p:outputPanel rendered="#{objectiveTemplateAction.questionList ne null and objectiveTemplateAction.questionList.size() eq 0}">
        <p class="lead">This template is under construction. We will launch this template very soon.</p>
        </p:outputPanel>

    </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Here is my Java Action class which will be used on a user request

```
    @Named("objectiveTemplateAction")
@Scope(ScopeType.VIEW)
public class EMRObjectiveTemplateAction implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EMRObjectiveTemplateAction.class);
    @Inject
    private EMRObjectiveTemplateService emrObjectiveTemplateService;
    @Inject
    private UserSession userSession;

    private EMRObjectiveTemplate objectiveTemplate = new EMRObjectiveTemplate();
    private EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestion question = new EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestion();

    private List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestion> questionList = null;
    private List<EMRObjectiveTemplate> objectiveTemplateList = new ArrayList<EMRObjectiveTemplate>();
    private List<EMRObjectiveQuestionType> questionTypeList = new ArrayList<EMRObjectiveQuestionType>();
    private List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOption> questionOptionList = new ArrayList<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOption>();
    private List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOption> questionOptionColumnList = new ArrayList<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOption>();
    private List<Long> optionMenuCountList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    private List<Long> optionRatingCountList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    private List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOptionMenu> optionMenuList = new ArrayList<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOptionMenu>();
    private List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOptionRating> optionRatingList = new ArrayList<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOptionRating>();

    private EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOptionValue optionValue = new EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOptionValue();

    private Long objectiveTemplateID;
    private Long questionTypeID;

    private String title;
    private String description;

    private String questionContainerName;

    private boolean showQuestionTabContainer = false;
    private String questionOptionName;
    private long optionMenuCount;
    private long optionRatingCount;
    private String menuOptionName;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
    this.objectiveTemplateList = this.emrObjectiveTemplateService.getAllTemplates();
    this.questionTypeList = this.emrObjectiveTemplateService.getAllQuestionType();

    // prefill optionMenuCountList with menuCount
    this.optionMenuCountList.add(1L);
    this.optionMenuCountList.add(2L);
    this.optionMenuCountList.add(3L);
    this.optionMenuCountList.add(4L);
    this.optionMenuCountList.add(5L);
    this.optionMenuCountList.add(6L);
    this.optionMenuCountList.add(7L);
    this.optionMenuCountList.add(8L);
    this.optionMenuCountList.add(9L);

    // prefill optionRatingCountList with ratingCount
    this.optionRatingCountList.add(2L);
    this.optionRatingCountList.add(3L);
    this.optionRatingCountList.add(4L);
    this.optionRatingCountList.add(5L);
    this.optionRatingCountList.add(6L);
    this.optionRatingCountList.add(7L);
    this.optionRatingCountList.add(8L);
    this.optionRatingCountList.add(9L);
    this.optionRatingCountList.add(10L);
    this.optionRatingCountList.add(11L);
    this.optionRatingCountList.add(12L);
    this.optionRatingCountList.add(13L);
    this.optionRatingCountList.add(14L);
    this.optionRatingCountList.add(15L);
    this.optionRatingCountList.add(16L);
    }

    /**
     * Recharge optionMenuList with requested optionMenuCount
     */
    public void rowNumbers() {
    this.optionMenuList = new ArrayList<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOptionMenu>();

    for(int i = 0; i < this.optionMenuCount; i++){
        this.optionMenuList.add(new EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOptionMenu());
    }
    }

    /**
     * Recharge optionRatingList with requested optionRatingCount
     */
    public void ratingNumbers() {
    this.optionRatingList = new ArrayList<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOptionRating>();

    for(int i = 0; i < this.optionRatingCount; i++){
        this.optionRatingList.add(new EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOptionRating());
    }
    }

    /**
     * Fetch all questions registered under this objectiveTemplateID
     */
    public void loadTemplateQuestionsByID(){
    System.out.println("Current Template ID: " + this.objectiveTemplateID);
    this.questionList = this.emrObjectiveTemplateService.loadTemplateQuestionsByID(this.objectiveTemplateID);
    System.out.println("Questions size: " + this.questionList.size());
    for(EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestion q : this.questionList){
        if(q.getQuestionType().getQuestionTypeVariant().equalsIgnoreCase("radio")){
        this.optionValue = new EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOptionValue();
        optionValue.setQuestion(q);
        }
    }
    }

    /**
     * Save filled template into database
     */
    public void fillAndSaveTemplate(){
    for(EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestion q : this.questionList){
        System.out.println("Option Value for Question " + q.getQuestionTitle() + " is: " + this.optionValue.getOptionValue());
//            System.out.println("Question ANswer: " + q.getQuestionAnswer().getQuestionAnswer());
    }
    }

    /**
     * Filter Options according to position from this optionList
     * @param optionsList
     * @return 
     */
    public List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOption> getColumnOptionsList(List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOption> optionsList) {
    List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOption> columnOptionsList = new ArrayList<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOption>();

    for(EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOption option : optionsList){
        if(option.getOptionPosition().equalsIgnoreCase("COLUMN")){
        columnOptionsList.add(option);
        }
    }

    return columnOptionsList;
    }

    // Getter - Setter
    public EMRObjectiveTemplate getObjectiveTemplate() {
    return objectiveTemplate;
    }

    public void setObjectiveTemplate(EMRObjectiveTemplate objectiveTemplate) {
    this.objectiveTemplate = objectiveTemplate;
    }

    public List<EMRObjectiveTemplate> getObjectiveTemplateList() {
    return objectiveTemplateList;
    }

    public void setEmrObjectiveTemplateList(List<EMRObjectiveTemplate> objectiveTemplateList) {
    this.objectiveTemplateList = objectiveTemplateList;
    }

    public Long getObjectiveTemplateID() {
    return objectiveTemplateID;
    }

    public void setObjectiveTemplateID(Long objectiveTemplateID) {
    this.objectiveTemplateID = objectiveTemplateID;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
    return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
    return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
    }

    public List<EMRObjectiveQuestionType> getQuestionTypeList() {
    return questionTypeList;
    }

    public void setQuestionTypeList(List<EMRObjectiveQuestionType> questionTypeList) {
    this.questionTypeList = questionTypeList;
    }

    public Long getQuestionTypeID() {
    return questionTypeID;
    }

    public void setQuestionTypeID(Long questionTypeID) {
    this.questionTypeID = questionTypeID;
    }

    public String getQuestionContainerName() {
    return questionContainerName;
    }

    public void setQuestionContainerName(String questionContainerName) {
    this.questionContainerName = questionContainerName;
    }

    public boolean isShowQuestionTabContainer() {
    return showQuestionTabContainer;
    }

    public void setShowQuestionTabContainer(boolean showQuestionTabContainer) {
    this.showQuestionTabContainer = showQuestionTabContainer;
    }

    public List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOption> getQuestionOptionList() {
    return questionOptionList;
    }

    public void setQuestionOptionList(List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOption> questionOptionList) {
    this.questionOptionList = questionOptionList;
    }

    public List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOption> getQuestionOptionColumnList() {
    return questionOptionColumnList;
    }

    public void setQuestionOptionColumnList(List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOption> questionOptionColumnList) {
    this.questionOptionColumnList = questionOptionColumnList;
    }

    public String getQuestionOptionName() {
    return questionOptionName;
    }

    public void setQuestionOptionName(String questionOptionName) {
    this.questionOptionName = questionOptionName;
    }

    public EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestion getQuestion() {
    return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestion question) {
    this.question = question;
    }

    public List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOptionMenu> getOptionMenuList() {
    return optionMenuList;
    }

    public void setOptionMenuList(List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOptionMenu> optionMenuList) {
    this.optionMenuList = optionMenuList;
    }

    public String getMenuOptionName() {
    return menuOptionName;
    }

    public void setMenuOptionName(String menuOptionName) {
    this.menuOptionName = menuOptionName;
    }

    public long getOptionMenuCount() {
    return optionMenuCount;
    }

    public void setOptionMenuCount(long optionMenuCount) {
    this.optionMenuCount = optionMenuCount;
    }

    public List<Long> getOptionMenuCountList() {
    return optionMenuCountList;
    }

    public void setOptionMenuCountList(List<Long> optionMenuCountList) {
    this.optionMenuCountList = optionMenuCountList;
    }

    public long getOptionRatingCount() {
    return optionRatingCount;
    }

    public void setOptionRatingCount(long optionRatingCount) {
    this.optionRatingCount = optionRatingCount;
    }

    public List<Long> getOptionRatingCountList() {
    return optionRatingCountList;
    }

    public void setOptionRatingCountList(List<Long> optionRatingCountList) {
    this.optionRatingCountList = optionRatingCountList;
    }

    public List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOptionRating> getOptionRatingList() {
    return optionRatingList;
    }

    public void setOptionRatingList(List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOptionRating> optionRatingList) {
    this.optionRatingList = optionRatingList;
    }

    public List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestion> getQuestionList() {
    return questionList;
    }

    public void setQuestionList(List<EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestion> questionList) {
    this.questionList = questionList;
    }

    public EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOptionValue getOptionValue() {
    return optionValue;
    }

    public void setOptionValue(EMRObjectiveTemplateQuestionOptionValue optionValue) {
    this.optionValue = optionValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is not a SSCCE question. http://sscce.org/

Comment: This is just a presentation layer code, I see you tag `hibernate`, but where is your `hibernate` code? once you map your table to your Entity object, you can persist your entity object to database via `PersistentContext`.